# Show Reviewing Pane in Word Client by default

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

**What I want**:
I'm editing a [`WordprocessingDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument(v=office.14).aspx), and adding some tracked changes in it. This part is done. Now, I want MS word to *show all revisions by default*, i.e., it shouldn't require user to click on the *red side bar* to open the tracked changes in the document.

[image: red side bar]

**What I did:** For this, I found a class [`RevisionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.revisionview(v=office.14).aspx), which adds the xml element `<w:revisionView />` in `settings.xml` under `w:settings` element. The `RevisionView` has some properties like `Comments`, `DisplayRevision`, `Formatting` etc. I explicitly set them all to `true`.

```
RevisionView revView = new RevisionView();
revView.DisplayRevision = new OnOffValue(true);
revView.Formatting = new OnOffValue(true);
revView.InkAnnotations = new OnOffValue(true);
revView.Markup = new OnOffValue(true);
revView.Comments = new OnOffValue(true);
```

and then I added this `revView` to the `Settings`:

```
Settings settings = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings;
settings.RemoveAllChildren<RevisionView>();
settings.AppendChild(revView);
settings.Save();
```

And then I reviewed the document xml explicitly, it is adding the following xml in the `settings`:

```
<w:revisionView w:markup="true" w:comments="true" w:insDel="true" w:formatting="true" w:inkAnnotations="true" />
```

But adding this element in settings doesn't affect the view. It isn't showing the revisions opened by default.

Then, for testing purpose, I changed the `zoom` element in the `settings.xml` by hand from `<w:zoom w:percent="100" />` to `<w:zoom w:percent="120" />`. What I expected was: word would change the zoom for this document from `100` to `120` now. But it didn't do that, the zoom was `100` even after changing to `120` in `settings.xml`.

One more thing: I can't use interop as I have to deploy this to a server, that's why I'm doing all this using OpenXmlSdk.

**What I'm asking:**

- Is it even possible to do *what i want*?
- If it is, then what am I doing wrong? Is `RevisionView` the option, on what should I rely?
- Is there a way to force word to apply (override the default application level settings) the settings provided in `settings.xml`?
- Why isn't word changing the zoom from 100 to 120?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers to your questions:

> Is it even possible to do what i want?

What you are trying to do is: Upon opening the docx file, have the Reviewing Pane be open automatically.  I could not find a way to force the Word client to do this with OpenXml.

> If it is, then what am I doing wrong? Is RevisionView the option, on what should I rely?

Its not possible, so the answer here is also no.

> Is there a way to force word to apply (override the default application level settings) the settings provided in settings.xml?

Yes using the [OpenXml SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).  The [Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.settings(v=office.15).aspx) Part has properties that you can control with code to alter the default Word client behavior.

> Why isn't word changing the zoom from 100 to 120?

I can't answer this without seeing your file.  Perhaps you did not save the file back correctly when you edited the file manually.

I was able to build a simple console app with the following code.  The app will change the zoom level for any Word file to 120%.  You need to add your file path to the code.

I generated most of this code using the [OpenXml Productivity Tool.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425).

Note - When building this in Visual Studio, don't forget to add `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` and `WindowsBase` to your project references.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {

        private static WordprocessingDocument document;
        private static System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String, OpenXmlPart> UriPartDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, OpenXmlPart>();
        private static System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String, DataPart> UriNewDataPartDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, DataPart>();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (document = WordprocessingDocument.Open("<DOCX FILE PATH HERE>", true))
            {
                BuildUriPartDictionary();
                ChangeParts();
            }

        }

        private static void BuildUriPartDictionary()
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.Queue<OpenXmlPartContainer> queue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<OpenXmlPartContainer>();
            queue.Enqueue(document);
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var part in queue.Dequeue().Parts)
                {
                    if (!UriPartDictionary.Keys.Contains(part.OpenXmlPart.Uri.ToString()))
                    {
                        UriPartDictionary.Add(part.OpenXmlPart.Uri.ToString(), part.OpenXmlPart);
                        queue.Enqueue(part.OpenXmlPart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ChangeParts()
        {
            ChangeDocumentSettingsPart1(((DocumentSettingsPart)UriPartDictionary["/word/settings.xml"]));
        }

        private static void ChangeDocumentSettingsPart1(DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingsPart)
        {
            Settings settings1 = documentSettingsPart.Settings;

            Zoom zoom1 = settings1.GetFirstChild<Zoom>();

            zoom1.Percent = "120";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't changing the zoom level using any code. I was manually editing the xml of docx file. And it saved correctly, I double checked it. Let me try this code too to see whether it changes the zoom level now or not.

Comment: Your code is just changing the zoom percent to `120%`, I've seen the changed XML files too, its changed to `120%` in `settings.xml`, but word is still showing it in `100%` zoom.

Comment: And one more thing, if `RevisionView` doesn't do what I was expecting from it, what does it actually do?

Comment: re: zoom not working.  Try starting with a fresh new document.  Then set the document zoom to 80% and save.  Run the console app on this document.  Then re-open to see if the zoom changes to 120%.  Your original document might be locked down.

Comment: The zoom value in settings.xml changes to 120%, but when opening with word, it still shows in 80%.

Comment: Ok it seems that you cannot preserve Word zoom settings in the document using OpenXML.  Only with PowerPoint and Excel.  Please see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Zoom-in-or-out-of-a-document-presentation-or-worksheet-0a0ebbed-10e7-444b-b16b-6f0c090f8ec7 .  Word preserves the zoom settings from the last time you ran word and ignores the settings.xml .  I will update the answer and leave the code for reference on how to change zoom with OpenXML.

Comment: Thanks. But still my main concern was showing the Reviewing Pane by default. Anyways thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, this question needs to be split in two.  Both questions (reviewing pane and zoom settings for word) are good and need a separate so post to separate the concerns.  At least change the title to one regarding the reviewing pane.  Right now it is misleading.